# Enabling Accessibility for Graphs for coreplot in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, graph, accessibility, core-plot

I have a graph view and pie chart in my application to display some information.

How to implement accessibility so as to help visually impaired users?

For example, when I tap on bar of graph, pie chart is displayed. So how can I implement accessibility for graph plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Plot currently does not have accessibility features. You could add accessibility information about the graph as a whole to the hosting view without too much trouble, but accessing individual graph elements would be difficult.

I opened an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=613) on the Core Plot issue tracker for this. Please comment there if you have specific needs you would like to see addressed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But in my case, I can not add accessibility to the whole view because in this case I will not be able to tap on plot and I have to open pie chart on click of plot. Please suggest some other way of implementing accessibility for same.

Comment: What kind of precision do you need? A tap anywhere on the graph or on specific data points? What kind of feedback do you need to provide the user to guide them to the correct spot on the graph to tap?